# Separate Data by Comma

Tags: java, regex, split

I am learning RegEx. completely a newbie :P

I wanted to separate numbers from the below data, which are separated by comma only

```
test
t,b
45,49
31,34,38,34,56,23,,,,3,23,23653,3875,3.7,8.5,2.5,7.8,2., 6 6 6 6 ,
,
.
.,/;,jm.m.,,n ,sdsd, 3,2m54,2 4,2m,ar ,SSD A,,B,4D,CE,S4,D,2343ES,SD
```

Suppose I am getting the above data from Form text field. Now I want to read the data only which are numbers seperated by comma

Solution should be[string]

```
45,49,31,34,38,34,56,23,3,23,23653,3875
```

all other data should be skipped. 
I tried something like this ^[0-9]+\,$

But it's also selecting 7 from 3.7, and 5 from 8.5, etc.....

Can anyone help me out in solving this!!

Comment: Do you intend this to be a **Java** question or a **JavaScript** question?

Comment: Use String[] results = secondString.split( ",\\s*" ); // split on commas

Comment: I want this to be Java question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are already splitting at commas and try to check whether the elements you get are numbers, use this expression: `^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$`, which means: "must begin with digits potentially followed by a dot and at least one more digit".

This would match `31` as well as `7.8`, but not `2.`, `6 6 6 6` or `2m54`.

Here's a part by part explanation of that expression:

- `^` means: matches must start at the first character
- `$` means: matches must end at the last character, so both together mean the entire string must match
- `\d+` means: one or more digits
- `(?: ... )` is a non-capturing group allowing to apply the `?` quantifier
- `\.` means: the literal dot
- `(?:\.\d+)?` thus means: zero or one occurences of a dot followed by at least one digit

Edit: if you only want integer numbers, just remove the group: `^\d+$` -> entire input must be one or more digits.

Edit 2: <strike>If you can prepend and append a comma to the input string</strike>(see Edit 4), you should be able to use this regex for getting all numbers: `(?<=,)\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(?=,)` (integers only would require you to remove the `(?:\.\d+)?` part).

That expression gets all numbers between two commas with possible whitespace between the commas and the number and catches the number into a group. This should prevent matches of `6 6 6 6` or `2m54`. Then just iterate over the matches to get all the groups.

Edit 3: Here's an example with your input string.

```
String input = "test\n" +
        "t,b\n" +
        "45,49\n" +
        "31,34,38,34,56,23,,,,3,23,23653,3875,3.7,8.5,2.5,7.8,2., 6 6 6 6 ,\n" +
        ",\n" +
        ".\n" +
        ".,/;,jm.m.,,n ,sdsd, 3,2m54,2 4,2m,ar ,SSD A,,B,4D,CE,S4,D,2343ES,SD\n";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?<=,|\\n)\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s*(?=,|\\n)" );    

Matcher m = p.matcher( input );

List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

while(m.find())
{
  numbers.add( m.group( 1 ) );
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString( numbers.toArray() ));

//prints: [45, 49, 31, 34, 38, 34, 56, 23, 3, 23, 23653, 3875, 3.7, 8.5, 2.5, 7.8, 3]
//removing the faction group: [45, 49, 31, 34, 38, 34, 56, 23, 3, 23, 23653, 3875, 3]
```

Edit 4: actually, you don't need to add commas, just use this expression:

```
`(?<=,|\n|^)\s*(\d+)\s*(?=,|\n|$)`
```

The groups at the start and end mean the match must follow the start of the input, a comma or a line break and be followed by the end of the input, a comma or a line break.

Comment: I want to split the data directly. First splitting with "," and then checking each string against might be performance overhead! In this case I tried something else(data.trim().matches("[0-9+]") in matching the pattern after splitting up.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and help. Can you explain me how you have written this. and I am newbie. getting by group(1) and ?<=   \s* all are bit confusing to me.

Comment: @nitin88 `group(1)` is documented by the JavaDoc on that method. It states that group 0 will be the entire match (which would include whitespace), so if you use capturing groups in your expression, they'll start at 1. `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are zero-width positive look behind and look ahead groups. For documentation on those, have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution i could come up with would be to replace anything that isn't a set of numbers separated by commas with the empty string.  So you could do `s.replaceAll("[^0-9]*,", ",")` If you have random newlines in there, you will probably want to add in a `s.replaceAll("\n", ",")`.  Then after those transformations, you can just do as suggested and split on commas.

Answer (score 0):

this experssion will give you all numbers you need (only numbers, no commas).

```
"^\d+|(?<=,)\d+$|(?<=,)\d+(?=,)"
```

see the grep example:

```
kent$  echo "31,34,38,34,56,23,,,,3,23,23653,3875,3.7,8.5,2.5,7.8,2., 6 6 6 6 ,
"|grep -oP "^\d+|(?<=,)\d+$|(?<=,)\d+(?=,)"

31
34
38
34
56
23
3
23
23653
3875
```

Comment: But if the data contains "34ES" it will get "34" from that. But it's supposed to be neglected. only numbers which are seperated by comma must be read and all other combinations must be ignored.